# Kubernetes ConfigMap mount single file instead of directory

Tags: file, kubernetes, configuration, configmap

Is it possible in Kubernetes to mount a file from a ConfigMap into an directory that already has other files?  E.g.

Base image filesystem:

```
/app/
  main/
    main.py
    test.py
```

ConfigMap contains one file, mounted.py, which should be mounted in /app/main/ alongside main.py and test.py.

Desired filesystem after deployment:

```
/app/
  main/
    main.py
    test.py
    mounted.py
```

What I have seen so far is that the ConfigMap is mounted to a new directory, so the closest I have come is like this:

```
/app/
  main/
    main.py
    test.py
    mounted/
      mounted.py
```

If I mount the ConfigMap to /app/main, then it clobbers the existing files from the base image.  E.g.

```
/app/
  main/
    mounted.py
```

Is there a good way to inject a single file like that?  (Actually multiple files in my real use case.)  I would prefer not to have separate directories for everything that will be injected by the ConfigMaps, since it deviates from the standard program architecture.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `subPath`:

```
volumeMounts:
  - name: config
    mountPath: /app/main/mounted.py
    subPath: mounted.py
```

The `mountPath` shows where it should be mounted, and `subPath` points to an entry inside the volume.

Please be aware of the limitation: when using subPath the configMap updates won't be reflected in your file. See the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#configmap) for details.

Comment: Thanks!  And if the volume contains more than just mounted.py, then only mounted.py will be extracted from it?

Comment: Correct, subPath will select only one element from the mounted volume

Comment: This works great except for the fact that updates to the ConfigMap are not reflected to files that are mounted with subPath.  It looks like that's just the way it is.

Comment: @RustyLemur you have to restart the pod if the configmap changes for the file to be updated in the pod